# How to make a counter for unique visitors for my webpage in php codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to make a counter for unique visitors in CodeIgniter using IP and session but this does not seem to work properly for me and I want to do it using cookies. So, I have written this function in my **Controller** -

```
function counter()
{
    $this->load->helper('cookie');
    $visitor = $this->input->cookie(urldecode(), FALSE);
    $ipadrs = $this->input->ip_address();
    if ($visitor == false)
    {
        $cookie = array(
            "name" => urldecode(),
            "value" => "$ipadrs",
            "expire" => time() + 7200,
            "secure" => false);
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
        $this->news->update_counter(urldecode());
    }
}
```

But this is not working, I have the update_counter function in my model.

I think I'm missing out on something very basic, any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cookie is not working count unique visitors,

A cookie is often used to identify a user. A cookie is a small file that the server embeds on the user's computer. Each time the same computer requests a page with a browser, it will send the cookie too. With PHP, you can both create and retrieve cookie values. cookie is not server side so not count you unique user.

http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/register-show-online-users-visitors_t

Here is a nice tutorial ,is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
function counter()
{
    $this->load->helper('cookie');
    $visitor = $this->input->cookie(urldecode(), FALSE);
    $ipadrs = $this->input->ip_address();
    if ($visitor == false)
    {
        $cookie = array(
            "name" => urldecode(),
            "value" => "$ipadrs",
            "expire" => 7200,
            "secure" => false);
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
        $this->news->update_counter(urldecode());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Aman please try explaining your answer to better understand the code you provide.

Comment: @Arman don't post answer from 2 different account. Edit your answer for better clarification or post comment rather than post new answer from new account.